# Installing pkg-config files to proper path on CentOS with automake

Tags: centos, automake, pkg-config

I have a couple projects I maintain that are built using automake (let's call them lib1 and lib2).  lib2 is dependent on lib1 as a library and I'm having some issues with the pkg-config defaults on CentOS.  Ideally, I'd like users to not have to set any environment variables to get everything to install properly.

Right now, it's just assuming `${PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig` as the destination for my .pc files, but on CentOS 7, the default for `${PREFIX}` is `/usr/local` but `pkgconfig` by default only looks in `/usr/share/pkgconfig` and `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig`.  Therefore, `lib2` can't find `lib1` with `pkg-config` and the configure script blows up.

So, the question is, how can my `make install` in `lib1` properly detect the directory to install the `pkg-config` files?

Comment: Consider adding search directories to the [`PKG_CONFIG_PATH`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303730/pkg-config-cannot-find-pc-files-although-they-are-in-the-path?rq=1) environment variable. `man pkg-config` has more details on env-vars.

Comment: That works fine.  However, I was looking for a solution so that common platforms (e.g. RHEL/CentOS) work with their default configurations!

Comment: So you want a solution based on `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro in `configure.ac`? If a directory isn't in built in to pkg-config's search path, you're going to need to set a search directory *somewhere*.

Comment: The question really isn't where to search for pacakges, but where to *install* the .pc files.  More like a macro to figure out where pkgconfig wants its pc files to go since ${prefix}/lib/pkgconfig seems to be wrong in this case.

Comment: `confg.site` controls where to find things, like a library directory of `lib64` on Red Hat-based systems. Fedora suffers the problem, too. Also see [config.site for vendor libs on Fedora x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46847939/608639).

Answer (score 2):

From `man pkg-config`

> PKG_INSTALLDIR(DIRECTORY)
>
> Substitutes the variable pkgconfigdir as the location where a module should install pkg-config .pc files. By  default  the
>   directory  is  $libdir/pkgconfig,  but the default can be changed by passing DIRECTORY.  The user can override through the
>    `--with-pkgconfigdir` parameter.

This allows you expose the install-directory of the pkg-config file to the user (and - if your distribution patched pkg-config to use non-standard search-paths, it hopefully will pick the proper default for your system).

Example:

configure.ac:

```
[...]
PKG_INSTALLDIR
[...]
```

Makefile.am:

```
[...]
pkgconfig_DATA = lib1.pc
[...]
```

Usage

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-pkgconfigdir=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
```

### Note

Please do not make distro-specific assumptions about where `pkg-config` will look for files.
Always use the defaults (they are defaults for good reasons), and provide a way to override these defaults for non-standard systems.

There are a lot distributions out there, and just because in my community one is prevailing, this doesn't mean that this is true for other communities (or not going to change).

If your distro does not follow the standard that's ok, but it should be consistent; if it fails to do be consistent (e.g. `pkg-config` looking for files in `/foo/baz`, but `PKG_INSTALLDIR` expanding `pkgconfigdir` to `/usr/lib/pkg-config`), then you should report a bug at your distribution.

Also I think it rather weird, that your `pkg-config` won't search for files in `/usr/local`.
E.g. on my Debian/sid system, it first searches `/usr/local` and then `/usr`:

```
$ which pkg-config
/usr/bin/pkg-config

$ strace -e trace=open pkg-config --cflags foo 2>&1  | grep /usr
open("/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/share/pkgconfig", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/pkgconfig", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/pkgconfig", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
$
```