# Incorrect @libdir@ when building *.pc using config.site?

Tags: configuration, libraries, autoconf

I'm working on Fedora x86_64. It uses `/lib64`, `/usr/lib64` and friends. I have the following `*.pc.in` file:

```
$ cat libcryptopp.pc.in
prefix=@prefix@
exec_prefix=@exec_prefix@
libdir=@libdir@
includedir=@includedir@
...
```

My `config.site` has the following. It was copied from Fedora's `config.site` at `/usr/share/config.site`. The copy was used because of [config.site for vendor libs on Fedora x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46847939/608639).

```
$ cat /usr/local/share/config.site
...

# Note: This file includes also RHEL/Fedora fix for installing libraries into
# "/lib/lib64" on 64bit systems.

if test -n "$host"; then
    # skip when cross-compiling
    return 0
fi

if test "$prefix" = /usr \
   || { test "$prefix" = NONE && test "$ac_default_prefix" = /usr ; }
then
    test "$sysconfdir" = '${prefix}/etc' && sysconfdir=/etc
    test "$sharedstatedir" = '${prefix}/com' && sharedstatedir=/var
    test "$localstatedir" = '${prefix}/var' && localstatedir=/var

    ARCH=`uname -m`
    for i in x86_64 ppc64 s390x aarch64; do
        if test $ARCH = $i; then
            test libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib64'
            break
        fi
    done
fi
```

However, after Autoconf processes my `*.pc.in` file:

```
$ autoreconf --install --force
...
$ ./configure
...

$ cat libcryptopp.pc
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include
...
```

Notice `libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib`, and not `libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib64`.

GCC is definitely building 64-bit binaries for the package. I did not add `-mx32` or `-m32`:

```
$ gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-redhat-linux
```

Why is the wrong `lib/` directory being used, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/usr/local/share/config.site` is wrong. Though it was copied from Fedora's `config.site` and placed in `/usr/local/share`, the prefix directories are wrong. The prefix test should use `/usr/local` and not `/usr`.

Below is the corrected one.

```
$ cat /usr/local/share/config.site
...

if test -n "$host"; then
    # skip when cross-compiling
    return 0
fi

if test "$prefix" = /usr/local \
   || { test "$prefix" = NONE && test "$ac_default_prefix" = /usr/local ; }
then
    test "$sysconfdir" = '${prefix}/etc' && sysconfdir=/etc
    test "$sharedstatedir" = '${prefix}/com' && sharedstatedir=/var
    test "$localstatedir" = '${prefix}/var' && localstatedir=/var

    ARCH=`uname -m`
    for i in x86_64 ppc64 s390x aarch64; do
        if test $ARCH = $i; then
            test "$libdir" = '${exec_prefix}/lib' && libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib64'
            break
        fi
    done
fi
```

Now, the next question is, why Fedora's `/usr/share/config.site` is not handling `prefix=/usr/local` properly. That's an open question at [Issue 1510073 : Autoconf does not honor libdir in config.site for "libdir=@libdir@" in *.pc file](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1510073), which has been closed as *NOT A BUG*.