# Cmake on centos/rhel system installs to .../lib64 while on ubuntu it installs to .../lib

Tags: c++, cmake, tritonserver

I'm trying to compile [triton inference server](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/tree/v2.13.0) on centos/rhel instead of ubuntu.
One problem I encounter is that I'll get the following error for some packages (e.g. protobuf, prometheus-cpp):

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Protobuf" with any
  of the following names:

    ProtobufConfig.cmake
    protobuf-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Protobuf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Protobuf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I already figured out that on ubuntu many packages get installed under `.../lib/cmake/.../*config.cmake` while on centos/rhel they get installed to `.../lib64/cmake../*config.cmake`.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to tell cmake to install everything under lib/cmake also on centos.

I've also tried to "go the other way around" and set search paths for specific packages to lib64 (e.g. I changed [this](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/blob/v2.13.0/build/CMakeLists.txt#L160) and [this](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/blob/v2.13.0/build/CMakeLists.txt#L243) line of code from `.../lib/cmake/...` to `.../lib64/cmake/...`) but when third party modules from other repositories are cloned I face the same issue.

So ideally, I'd like an easy way to tell cmake in the "main" CMakeLists.txt (there are multiple CMakeLists.txt and some get generated through `make` later in the build process) that everything should be installed to `lib`.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you faced with the problem, opposite to one specified in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626164/make-install-installs-libraries-in-usr-lib-instead-of-usr-lib64). But solution could be the same. E.g. setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` variable.

Comment: I tried to set it in the CMakeLists.txt (using `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBIDR:STRING=lib`) as well as using it in `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib ...` but nevertheless the *config.cmake files are still under lib64

Comment: Which project you are tried to install that way? E.g. Protobuf [respects](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/install.cmake) directories set in the module [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html), so setting variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` should affect on the location of Protobuf's config file.

Comment: I got it working, the problem was that protobuf & prometheus-cpp were actually referenced via `FetchContent_Declare` in another repository. Once I changed it in that remote repo by adding `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBIDR:STRING=lib` it works and everything got compiled correctly! Thanks a lot for your help!