# Keep gcc linker from using non-system libraries found in system /lib64 folder

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

I am porting a large C++ library (libcoro.so) and example application (coro-example.cpp) from Windows to RedHat Linux 7.4. I have very little development experience on Linux, so this is probably a 'newbie' question. I have libcoro and the example app compiling, linking, and running on my RHEL 7.4 VM. However, the gcc linker fails to link the app on the customer's RHEL 7.4 machine when he tries to link coro-example.o to libcoro.so. The error message is:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libusb-0.1.so.4, needed by ./bin/libcoro.so not
>   found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
>  libcoro.so: undefined
>   reference to 'usb_open'
>  libcoro.so: undefined reference to
>   'usb_release_interface'
>  ...etc...

Running 'ldd coro.so' on my machine displays:

> libusb-0.1.so.4 => /lib64/libusb-0.1.so.4 (0x00007f71115db000)
>   ...etc...

And on the customer's machine:

> libusb-0.1.so.4 => not found
>  [many other libs] => not found
>  ...etc...

Indeed, these libraries are in my /lib64 folder, but are not in the customer's. I'm not sure how they got installed on my machine. I have access to the missing libraries and can deliver them with my libcoro.so library. I really want my app to be self-contained and run on any RHEL 7.x machine. My question is:

What is the best way to identify which libraries are not part of the RHEL 7.x installation and have the linker fail on my machine if I'm not delivering a local copy? I tried linking with -nodefaultlibs, but the link fails on functions like printf() and I haven't found a way to locate these standard libraries. They don't appear to be in /lib64.

Is there a way to exclude /lib64 from the default library search?

Comment: *"... these libraries are in my /lib64 folder..."* - Red Hat and Fedora use `lib64/` on 64-bit machines (but not 32-bit machines). Debian and Ubuntu uses a more traditional scheme, where libraries go in `lib/`. Also see your `/usr/share/config.site`, which is used by `pkg-config`. Also see [config.site for vendor libs on Fedora x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46847939/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jww My RHEL 7.4 VM doesn't have `/usr/share/config.site`. Where else might I look for it?

Comment: Try `find /usr -name config.site`. I don't have access to a Red Hat machine, so I test on Fedora and CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a linker switch `-Wl,--no-undefined` which seems to do what I want. It fails to link and generates an error is the library is isn't explicitly named. Also, the command `ldd libcoro.so` lists all dependencies and where they are being resolved. I also found this [this article](http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/) very helpful.