# pkg-config cannot find gtk+-3.0

Tags: node.js, debian, gtk, node-gyp, pkg-config

I am trying to use `libui-node` to build a Node.js project.

```
$ yarn add libui-node
```

This gives an error:

> node-gyp configure build Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the
>   pkg-config search path. 
>   Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing `gtk+-3.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'gtk+-3.0' found gyp: Call to 'pkg-config gtk+-3.0
>   --cflags-only-I | sed s/-I//g' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp gyp ERR! configure error
>   ...

So then I follow the instructions:

```
$ pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags-only-I | sed s/-I//g
```

> Package gtk+-3.0 was
>   not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the
>   directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment
>   variable No package 'gtk+-3.0' found

However, I have already installed gtk+-3.0 with this command:

```
$  sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev
```

I am on Ubuntu 17.10.

My `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

> /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:

How should I configure my system so that it can find this library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pkg-config cannot find .pc files although they are in the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303730/pkg-config-cannot-find-pc-files-although-they-are-in-the-path)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT:**

> Showing the default locations where `pkg-config` looks for .pc files is more easily done with `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` as stated by @BrettHale in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11309122/518853). This uses a special virtual `pkg-config` package to expose `pkg-config` configuration. This is easier than parsing the debug logs or using `strace` (which saved my day more than once), but the point was more on teaching how to get information when we don't know where to look.

**Original answer:**

You shouldn't have to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. Usually the paths your distro uses match the ones `pkg-config` will look into by default.

`pkg-config` looks for the `.pc` associated with GTK+ 3. As you have installed the `libgtk-3-dev` development package, you find in it the `.pc` files it provides using:

```
$ dpkg -L libgtk-3-dev | grep '\.pc'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gdk-wayland-3.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-unix-print-3.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-3.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gdk-3.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-wayland-3.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gdk-x11-3.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-x11-3.0.pc
```

Those results are for my Ubuntu 14.04 system, but on Ubuntu 17.10 for amd64, the file has not moved, it's still:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-3.0.pc
```

Now the file is named `gtk+-3.0.pc`, so the name of the module as expected by `pkg-config` is that name without the `.pc` extension, which is `gtk+-3.0`. This helps making sure you didn't make a typo in the module name.

For example,

```
pkg-config --modversion gtk+3.0
```

would tell you it can't find `gtk+3.0` and that you should change `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, but in fact the real problem is that it's the wrong module name as there's a missing `-` character.

Now, we will run `pkg-config` in its default configuration, without customized `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. This will check your system's default behavior, with `pkg-config` looking only in its default paths:

```
unset PKG_CONFIG_PATH
pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0
```

If this returns the version of GTK+, you're done. If you still have the error message saying it's not found though, then you may check where `pkg-config` looks by default in the debug logs. Just add the `--debug` option:

```
pkg-config --debug --modversion gtk+-3.0
```

This returns a quite verbose log of where it detects the `.pc` files.
Here a the first few lines on may Ubuntu 14.04 system:

```
Option --debug seen
Option --modversion seen
Error printing enabled by default due to use of --version, --libs, --cflags, --libs-only-l, --libs-only-L, --libs-only-other, --cflags-only-I, --cflags-only-other or --list. Value of --silence-errors: 0
Error printing enabled
Adding virtual 'pkg-config' package to list of known packages
Cannot open directory '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig' in package search path: No such file or directory
Cannot open directory '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig' in package search path: No such file or directory
Cannot open directory '/usr/local/share/pkgconfig' in package search path: No such file or directory
Scanning directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig'
[...]
```

Notice the lines starting with `Cannot open directory` and `Scanning directory`. They tell you where `pkg-config` is looking. Let's only display that:

```
$ pkg-config --debug --modversion gtk+-3.0 2>&1 | egrep "(Cannot open|Scanning) directory"
Cannot open directory '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig' in package search path: No such file or directory
Cannot open directory '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig' in package search path: No such file or directory
Cannot open directory '/usr/local/share/pkgconfig' in package search path: No such file or directory
Scanning directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig'
Scanning directory '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
Scanning directory '/usr/share/pkgconfig'
```

Now you have all the locations that are searched for. Those are the same in my 14.04 and in Ubuntu 17.04 (I checked that in a docker container). Some of those directories exist, others don't. You will notice that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` is there for me, so `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-3.0.pc` is found.

If it's not there for you, then yes, you may add it to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```

This should now return the version of the GTK+ library detected by `pkg-config`:

```
pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0
```

Comment: I tried in a docker container, `docker run -it ubuntu:17.04`, then `apt-get update && apt-get install pkg-config libget-3-dev`. And it works out of the box, so I don't know what's specific to you environment.

Answer (score -1):

It is due to .bbappend file removeing the x11 from the gtk+3 below path

```
cat meta-freescale/recipes-graphics/gtk+/gtk+3_%.bbappend

PACKAGECONFIG_remove_imxgpu2d = " \
${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "wayland", "x11", "", d)} \
"

CFLAGS_append_imxgpu2d = " \
-DLINUX \
${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'wayland', '-DEGL_API_FB
-DEGL_API_WL', '', d)} \
```

Instead of **remove** add **append** it will build successfully.