# Unable to display image opencv (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, gtk, ubuntu-20.04

I finally managed to build the opencv4.5.4 library from source but now I'm facing errors that I'm unable to fix.

I'm using this medium article as my guide https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-opencv-for-visual-studio-code-using-ubuntu-os-9398b2f32d53

When I try to execute a simple program that prints the version of opencv installed, it executes without errors.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
  std::cout << "OpenCV Version: "<< CV_VERSION << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
CC = g++
PROJECT = new_output
SRC = new.cpp
LIBS = `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
$(PROJECT) : $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(SRC) -o $(PROJECT) $(LIBS)
```

Output:

```
username@Inspiron-7591:~/SeePluPlu/opencv-test$ sudo make
g++ new.cpp -o new_output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
username@Inspiron-7591:~/SeePluPlu/opencv-test$ sudo ./new_output 
OpenCV Version: 4.5.4-dev
```

Now when I try to run another program to display an image things get out of hand really quick.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
  
// Driver code
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Read the image file as
    // imread("default.jpg");
    Mat image = imread("lena.jpg",IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  
    // Error Handling
    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Image File "
             << "Not Found" << endl;
  
        // wait for any key press
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }
  
    // Show Image inside a window with
    // the name provided
    imshow("Window Name", image);
  
    // Wait for any keystroke
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
username@Inspiron-7591:~/SeePluPlu/opencv-test$ ./new_output 
Gtk-Message: 18:49:40.321: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 18:49:40.324: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) /home/username/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 120542625076320 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'

Aborted (core dumped)
```

but when I give root privilages...

```
username@Inspiron-7591:~/SeePluPlu/opencv-test$ sudo ./new_output 
Gtk-Message: 18:49:31.985: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) /home/username/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 112126257730176 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'

Aborted
```

when I rerun the binary file (./new_output) over and over again I end up getting assertion errors as well.

I searched for loading the canberra-gtk-module and atk-bridge but whatever I found was not of any help

- https://askubuntu.com/a/565789
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1300284
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed (all solutions in this thread)

Note: I'm positive that the image is being read and I'm able to print its size using image.size() function and I think it has something to do with the imshow() function... Not sure.

**Any** help or detail is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to build opencv4 again, I was able to figure out that cmake was unable to find the gtk+-3.0 module that's installed in my system.

```
username@Inspiron-7591:~$ pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
```

even though it was already installed...

```
username@Inspiron-7591:~$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
[sudo] password for username: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgtk-3-dev is already the newest version (3.24.20-0ubuntu1).
libgtk-3-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I stumbled upon this gem of a thread while googling my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038996/15341103 and I was able to make pkgconfig detect gtk+-3.0

I rebuilt opencv4 again this time and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to the image per se, its possibly an unitialized variable passed to a memory allocation routine.

`what():  OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) /home/username/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 112126257730176 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'`

Put a break point in **alloc.cpp** to figure out who is requesting `allocate 112126257730176 bytes`

Comment: What about *Failed to load module "atk-bridge"* and *Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"*?

Comment: The question relates to openCV, as such an absence of a library should not cause a memory allocation error. OpenCV should detect the absence of a library and either gracefully shutdown or try to use a fallback. Correct install of gtk may remove this error - but I think the user has detected an internal bug as well.

Comment: I fixed the issue, turns out it was something to do with the gtk modules, I rebuilt opencv to make sure that the compiler was able to detect the gtk-+3.0 module this time during the build process. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038996/15341103 <-- this answer helped me solve it.