# how to add directory to search path in msys2?

Tags: c, gtk3, msys, pkg-config

I am trying to install GTK 3 for C using [this](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows) tutorial

after following the full install instructions and trying to build a simple program using [this](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/) I was met with

```
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gtk+-3.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

error. So I re did all the steps and noticed [image: Note that 'C:/msys64/mingw64/share' is not in search path]

Plus after installing the toolchain base-devel for C,C++ I checked if the old problem stayed using `pkg-config --modversion gtk+3.0` I found this command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031080/pkg-config-cannot-find-gtk-3-0)

```
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gtk+-3.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

same issue. So my question is, Is there a way to add C:/msys64/mingw64/share/ to search path?

Comment: The [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) (the magenta `MSYS` in the terminal prompt) doesn't match the package you use (note prefix `mingw-w64-x86_64-`). Restart the terminal using `c:\msys64\mingw64.exe`, then it should say `MINGW64`. Make sure all compilers and libraries you install also have this package prefix, only use unprefixed packages for simple utils like `grep`, etc.

Comment: That's it please post this as answer, Plus why don't the official docs address this issue!! and also how do I get this to work in the command prompt of powerShell ?

Comment: This is a big topic, and I don't have time to write a full-fledged answer now. :( I wouldn't bother with PS. In theory, you just need to set some environment variables (probably the ones named `PKG_CONFIG_??`).

Answer (score -1):

Use this command:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/c/msys64/mingw64/share
```

Comment: I don't think adding `/mingw64/share` has any effect. The pkg-config files are in `/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig`, and I think pkg-config only checks `PKG_CONFIG_*` variables, not `PATH`. In any case, you shouldn't mess with the variables manually when you can just enable the right MSYS2 environment.